# How can i align <span> to the left?

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float, css-position

i need to align `<span>` to the left. I can't use:

```
position:absolute;
float:left;
```

Because when i use these, it is align in left but it cause me other problems.
Does anybody know about some other option ?

EDIT:
OK, i used `float:left;` and it is on the left side but the other span beneath simply dont stay on his line. I cant do `</br>` after span i tried this, i tried `clear:left;` it didnt help neither.

Comment: Define _"I need to align <span> to the left"_. Show us your markup of what you have tried, or make a fiddle.

Comment: @Vucko Agree. I would really love to help but this question is very unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [how floats work](http://phrogz.net/css/understandingfloats.html).

Using `absolute` means that you can position your span with the given distances to the edges of your div. Hence, using `float: left;` in addition to this doesn't make sense.

Instead you can do absolute positioning:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
```

Comment: IMHO this is the best answer yet. You should bring your _how floats work_ link more in front. I think this is a main point to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your span as a display:block or inline-block and remove the position:absolute line. Then it will float left with the declaration that you have above.

```
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem that you are encountering with may be that "All the other elements take the space to the right". And that is exactly what they are supposed to do. To avoid this, grab your elements that are floating to the right automatically and do this:

```css
clear:both;
```